# Как вывести числа от 1 до 100, перенося каждый десяток цифр на новую строку?

Tags: c#

Требуемый вывод:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 ....................... 30
.
.
.
91 ....................... 100
```

Пока получается всё в строку:

```
... 100
```

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: А как вы выводите каждое число?

Comment: `for (byte i = 0; i < 101; i++)
 {                                          
     Console.Write(i + " ");
 }`

Comment: В конце цикла вашего добавьте `if (i%10==0) Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
    
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine();    
}
```

`%` - означает остаток от деления. То есть, каждый раз, когда у нас число кратно 10, мы пропускаем строчку.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть вариант с `Linq`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Enumerable
          .Range(1, 100)
          .ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}{1}", i, (i % 10) != 0 ? ' ' : '\n'));
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Action<T> what) {
        foreach (T i in data) {
            what?.Invoke(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж про `.Chunk` стоит вспомнить

Comment: Он же с 6го .net и выше.

Comment: И что? Вы из мира Unity что-ли?